# I need to remove a piece of every line in my json file

Tags: json, regex

I have a json output on my notepad and i know it is not in the correct format. At the end of each line there is a time stamp which is causing the bad format. I want to get rid of it using find and replace since the file is pretty big. The format is as follows :

"eventtimestamp": "05 23 2017 04:01:02"}

The above piece comes in at the end of every line. How can i get rid of it using find a replace or any other way.

All help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: To clarify... the values in the timestamp change, correct?  And you still need the closing curly-bracket to keep the JSON valid, correct?

Comment: @STW Hi, yes the values in the time stamp change and no, i do not need the last curly bracket as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to alter every line in a consistent way then regex find/replace is a good option.  Free tools like atom.io, Notepad++, and plenty of others offer this feature.

Assuming "eventtimestamp" is constant, then a simple regex that says "find everything starting with "eventtimestamp" and up to a '}'" will work.

> "eventtimestamp".*(?=})

And "replace" that with an empty string.

---

ps) [here's a demo](https://regexr.com/3h4kf) of the regex in regexr.com--hovering over the parts of the pattern will explain what they do.

Comment: i gave it a try using notepadd++ but it does not find a match. This is what i used : "eventtimestamp".*(?=})

Comment: the '}' inside the regex probably needs to be escaped: `\}` and it might work.  But, since you don't want to keep the closing curly-bracket you can remove the entire `(?=})` bit--which says "stop before the curly bracket"

Comment: hi, i used the following expression and it worked. Thank you so much!
"eventtimestamp":.*

Comment: no problem, welcome to StackOverflow... and have fun with regex's: https://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure that the `eventtimestamp` field always comes in at the end of a line and/or as the last element of the object, prefer that kind of pattern: `"eventtimestamp":\s*"[^"]+",?`.

Note the useful surrounded excepted character class pattern `"[^"]+"` that can be declined with any other delimiter.